# Recurrence relation for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, legendre-polynomials

I am reading a book that talks about series solutions of differential equations, and I couldn't seem to understand the following question:

Consider the differential equation

[image]

and use the assumption that

[image]

then find the recurrence relation for the infinite series to be a solution.

I am not entirely sure what the question means, especially about the recurrence relation. The only thing that I could get from the book is that the original equation is the  Legendre differential equation. How should I approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can (formally) differentiate the power series (two times). Then plug the power series and its derivatives into the differential equation and reorder by powers of $x$. The coefficients of the $x^n$ will be lienar combinations of the $c_n$. In fact, they will be a recurrence relation for calculating the $c_n$ inductively.

Answer (score 4):

I will make a similar exercise with a simpler equation. I hope that you see the point.

Consider
$$xy+y'=0$$
with $$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_nx^n$$
Then
$$y'=\sum_{k=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1}$$
Now substitute:
$$x\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_nx^n+\sum_{k=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1}=0$$
That is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{n-1}x^n+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (n+1)c_{n+1}x^n=0$$
For each $n\ge 1$ we have that
$$c_{n-1}+(n+1)c_{n+1}=0$$
or
$$c_{n+1}=-\frac{c_{n-1}}{n+1}$$
This would be the recurrence relation for this example.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you!